# How to undo a file cut in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally pressed Command-X in the files tab instead of in the code, and it has darkened the "resetApi" file. I'm not exactly sure what negative effects this has, but it does not look right and Command-Z won't undo it.[image of what I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X1qY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command-X means you have tried to move the file. So you just have to COMMAND-V to paste the file.